# create table and load data in same command

Tags: hive

To create a table and load data in that table using a .tbl file we need to, first create the schema and then load the data?

Is not possible to do both operations just in one command, like this command below?

```
create external table customer (
    C_CUSTKEY INT, 
    C_NAME STRING, 
    C_ADDRESS STRING, 
    C_NATIONKEY INT, 
    C_PHONE STRING, 
    C_ACCTBAL DOUBLE, 
    C_MKTSEGMENT STRING, 
    C_COMMENT STRING
) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/user/hadoopadmin/tables/customer.tb.';
```

Because I try to do this above command first and the schema was created but when I tried to do "select count(*) from customer" I get 0 rows.

But using the first command to create the schema and then use "LOAD DATA INPATH" command to load the data works. Now with `select count(*)` I get the number of rows in table.

So its necessary to execute two commands? Its not possible with my first code example with "LOCATION" option, or the first code have some issue and because of that didnt work?

Comment: looks like you have a typo in the file name ("customer.tb.") in the DDL. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I thanks for your help. It seems that its because I was using customer.tbl and needs to be just customer! With just customer it is working!